# Linux: Search for old files.... copy the oldest ones to a location... (+- Verify copy)... then delete them

Tags: linux, bash, raspbian

I need help with file handling in on Raspbian Stretch Lite running on Raspberry Pi Zero --- fresh install, updated.

The following script is run periodically as a cron job:

```
partition=/dev/root
imagedir=/etc/opt/kerberosio/capture/
if [[ $(df -h | grep $partition | head -1 | awk -F' ' '{ print $5/1 }' | tr ['%'] ["0"]) -gt 90 ]];
then
    echo "Cleaning disk"
    find $imagedir -type f | sort | head -n 100 | xargs -r rm -rf;
fi;
```

Essentially when the SD card is >90% full the oldest 100 files in a directory are deleted.

I want to add some functionality:
1) Copy the 100 oldest files to a NAS drive mounted on the file system and 
2) Verify successful copy and 
3) Delete the files that were copied.

I have found the following string which may be helpful in the modification of the script above:

```
find /data/machinery/capture/ -type f -name '*.*' -mtime +1 -exec mv {} /data/machinery/nas/ \;
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have made a clear request for help above:  "I want to add some functionality: 1) Copy the 100 oldest files to a NAS drive mounted on the file system and 2) Verify successful copy and 3) Delete the files that were copied."